# How to install an Automator action from unidentified developer?

Tags: macos, security, automator, keychain, certificate

I downloaded an APN certificate from [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/) from the Apple Developer configuration pane. It's an `.action` file that I cannot open, though.

[image: Action Installer]

> Do you want to install the "downloadCertificateContent" action?
>
> Actions are the components of Automator workflows. Installing this action will make it available in the Automator library.

[image: Action Installer Error]

> Action could not be installed.
>
> The action "downloadCertificateContent" was not loaded because it is from an unidentified developer.

I already enabled Third Party Actions in the Automator preferences:

[image: Automator Third Party Action Preferences]

> Third Party Automator Actions
>
> Enable Automator Actions from Third Parties

I downloaded it from here:

[image: Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles certificate download page]

What the heck is going on? Why is the action from an unidentified developer in the first place? The developer should be Apple. What are they doing, again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you've downloaded is not an action file. The file is a certificate and as such cannot be used with Automator and loaded as an action.

Instead rename the file to have the extension `.cer` and double-click it to load it in `Keychain Access`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, an extension of my browser messed the name up and called the file `downloadCertificateContent.action`, because the HTTP endpoint on the Apple page is called that way. It actually served the `.cer` file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to download the `.cer` files using Safari.